# How to use Git or Subversion?

Tags: php, svn, web, github

I code all by myself, and I have 1 website . but i dont ever use subversion or github. Question is:
How to develop on souce code of my website server and update it when develop complete.
In this case , should use github or subversion.

Truthly , i read and using github then try to create repository but anyone can watch mycode . I dont want that.

I want 1 guide easy for very begin about this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Git locally. So no need for Github. There is a video serie on www.tekpub.com about Git.

Comment: git or subversion in this case is better ? I want learn fast 1 in 2.

Comment: subversion requires a server, git does not, so git in this case.

Comment: which server use subverion, you can give short explain . My website's server or other server for subversion ?

Comment: Whichever server you want. The main point is, you're going to have to setup that up and it requires some work and elbow grease.

Comment: @icco Subversion doesn't require a server. You can run it directly against a local (or even remote) file repository.

Comment: @Matt I think the distinction Sergio is going for is that Subversion requires a "remote" repository where commits are sent, even if that repository is actually local to your machine. Git does a better job of hiding this.

Answer (score 2):

SVN and GIT are two completely different types of code repository patterns. If you using GIT you don't need a central server and can create a repository locally on your machine. I recommend you get familiar with this website just to get a basic overview of what a DVCS is and how it can affect the way you code.

[HgInit](http://hginit.com/)

The good news is that you aren't familiar with any VCS (I assume) and that means you won't get mixed up when trying to learn GIT coming from SVN.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already know the basics of how to commit/push/etc with git, which your answer suggests you do, the problem is that your repo is set to be public and not private. You can change this on the repo's admin page, assuming your github account has enough private repos left (The lowest account level that supports this is USD$7/month iirc). There are [other git hosts](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitHosting) which you can use for free that provide private repos.

Answer (score 0):

As Roger said, you can use Git locally and do not need a server for that.

<strike>For SVN you need a central repository server, that usually does not correspond to your live webserver.</strike>

You will need a running Apache server and install SVN as an additional module for it. Once you have a subversion server running, you can then add repositories to it, normally one repository per project.

Usually you would have a local subversion installation on a development server in your local network or even (as you work alone) on your local machine, using a distinct host/port configuration for SVN, e.g. you could use `localhost:80` for your development of the live website, and `localhost:9999` for your SVN installation. There are several guides for installing SVN on [Windows](http://www.dmbcllc.com/Articles/SubVersion/ServerInstallation/tabid/173/Default.aspx), [Linux](http://www.subversionary.org/howto/setting-up-a-subversion-server-on-ubuntu-gutsy-gibbon-server) and [MacOS](http://www.sonzea.com/articles/subversion-trac.html) found via google.

Both version control systems require some initial work to get it, but I personally prefer Git over SVN. Check out [the Git guide on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide) or [the SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).

Comment: It's not true that you need to run a server to use SVN, the repository can also live on a local filesystem and be accessed directly.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I find SVN easier to learn and install than GIT (but I guess that depends on person ;) and OS - I'm on windows unfortunately)

That's why I choose some free personal host for that. I tried [BeanStalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/) and [XP-Dev](http://www.xp-dev.com/). The first one, is cleaner and much more user-friendly... and offer GIT or SVn ! But you got only 1 personal project available for free. 
The second one is ugly but quite performant, 2 personal projects but only with SVN for free.